# Recursive Function to reverse a string C++

Tags: c++, recursion, reverse

I have previously found this code in doing a recursion on string reversing but I couldn't understand how the code work, could I possibly get some explanation? thank you!

```cpp
std::string reverse(std::string str) {
    if(str.length()==0)
        return "";  
    return reverse(str.substr(1)) + str[0];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the explanation in the following diagram, I suspect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have string "abcdab".

1. you ask for str.length() which equals to 6.
2. you take its substring from index 1 so it's "bcdab"
3. you take the first symbol and reverse it with substring. Now you have "bcdaba"
4. repeat 1 so you'll have "cdabab" then "dababc" and so on

Comment: by that logic wouldn't it return back into abcdab?
Edit: Nevermind I have understood the logic now thank you very much!